# Dropdown opens with accordion

Tags: angularjs, drop-down-menu

I'm working with angular and have the next issue: I have a group of accordions which have a dropdown menu on the header. I want to expand the last added element to the group of accordions, so I added an additional paramater _isOpen and when I add a new element: _isOpen = true. Everything works, but dropdown on the accordions' header opens as well as accordion.

Here's how it looks in angular:

```
<uib-accordion close-others="oneAtATime">
    <uib-accordion-group template-url="./custom-template.html" is-open="element._isOpen" ng-repeat="element in rlFull.elements track by element.Id" scroll-glue>
        <div class="testing-table" ui-ace="{ onLoad : aceLoaded, mode: 'gherkin', theme: 'chrome'}" ng-model='element.Text' join-steps-array style="height : 200px"></div>
    </uib-accordion-group>
</uib-accordion>
```

And part from template with dropdown meny:

```
<div class="action-block">
    <div uib-dropdown="dropdown" class="dropdown-holder">
        <button uib-dropdown-toggle="" class="btn">
            Actions
            <span class="ico-dropdown"></span>
        </button>
        <ul role="menu" class="dropdown-menu">
            <li>
                <a href="" data-ng-click="$parent.element.saveChanges();">Save</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="" ng-click="$parent.element.deleteElement($parent.element)">Delete</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm not able to build out an example of your code currently to test but have you tried using ngRepeat `$last` instead for the `is-open`? It might be simpler than what you currently have.

Comment: you need to stop propagation of event, so that accordion will not get that event

Comment: @MatthewGreen If I use $last then the last accordion is always open, even after iniatil loading of the page.

Answer (score 0):

I added is-open = false for uib-dropdown and it helped me:

```
<div class="action-block">
    <div uib-dropdown="dropdown" class="dropdown-holder" is-open="false">
        <button uib-dropdown-toggle="" class="btn">
            Actions
            <span class="ico-dropdown"></span>
        </button>
        <ul role="menu" class="dropdown-menu">
            <li>
                <a href="" data-ng-click="$parent.element.saveChanges();">Save</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="" ng-click="$parent.element.deleteElement($parent.element)">Delete</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```